# What does "facade" mean in some functions of LibAOM software

Tags: codec

AS shown in the image, there are many cases like this in Libaom, a "facade" is followed the function name, but i dont know what it means, Is there anyone know what it means?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome! It would be better if you included the code as text.

Comment: void av1_predict_intra_block_facade(const AV1_COMMON* cm, MACROBLOCKD* xd, int plane, int blk_col, int blk_row, TX_SIZE tx_size)
{
    const MB_MODE_INFO* const mbmi = xd->mi[0];
    struct macroblockd_plane* const pd = &xd->plane[plane];
    const int dst_stride = pd->dst.stride;
    uint8_t* dst = &pd->dst.buf[(blk_row * dst_stride + blk_col) << MI_SIZE_LOG2];
    const PREDICTION_MODE mode = (plane == AOM_PLANE_Y) ? mbmi->mode : get_uv_mode(mbmi->uv_mode);
......

Comment: Great, that is hepful. It will be easier for people to read it if you update your question to include it there.